# draw a rectangle with custom texts around an image in d3 dendrogram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, dendrogram

I am trying to draw a rectangle shape where I can fit some data in a d3 dendrogram. But I am not sure how I can do this. I have the initial plunkr available here: http://plnkr.co/edit/AoqY1xoRlwyK3VAxYuhz?p=preview
Here is what I know I can do for appending text:

```
  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
```

Basically I want to draw a shape like this around every node:
[image]

Can anyone help me here or point me to some doc which I can refer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have group elements here. That being said, all you need is to append your rectangles (don't mind the magic numbers here, you can change them later):

```
var nodeRect = nodeEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("height", 14)
      .style("fill", "dodgerblue")
      .attr("rx", 4)
      .attr("ry", 4)
      .attr("y", -7);
```

Then, after the text selection being created/appended, calculate the length of the texts. Here I'm using `this.nextSibling.nextSibling` because I know where the texts are in relation to the rectangles:

```
nodeRect.attr("width", function(d) {
        return this.nextSibling.nextSibling.getComputedTextLength() + 30
    })
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return d._children || d.depth === 0 ? -(this.nextSibling.nextSibling.getComputedTextLength() + 14) : -14
    });
```

Here is your updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/a32rYZT6cSZ0c5zQrC6W?p=preview

Comment: Thank you Master of D3. You are genious. your answer almost solved my problem.